# Extract last part of URL in HTML / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, url

How do I extract a part of the URL in HTML and display the error message?

Example: URL of my web page: `file_upload/code/email/Invalid_File_Type/`.

I want to extract the message Invalid File Type to display the error. But how?

Using Django 1.4, I tried passing the error message from py file but couldn't get it to work for some reason :(

Comment: [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript by using "window.location" property and alert it.

Example

```
<script>
alert("Your current URL is "+location);
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Try this

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var url = "file_upload/code/email/Invalid_File_Type/";
    var splt = url.split("/");
    var lngth = splt.length;
    var lst_value = splt[(lngth-2)]; 
    alert(lst_value);
});
</script>
```

this will get the last part of the url.

Comment: I changed the url with the given url